# How do I use the Google Closure Compiler to build one file?

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

The question is a little more complicated than the title suggests, so allow me to elaborate. I have a project that is split into two repositories. The both use Google Closure for dependency management and compilation. I need to deliver a compiled version of project A to project B. Project B does advanced optimizations, so project A must be whitespace only. The problem is that I can't find a way to satisfy all my requirements for compiled A, which are:

- It must be ordered by dependency
- There can be no `goog` base code, i.e., `var goog=goog||{}...`
- Similarly, there can be no goog.provides or goog.requires
- It must be whitespace-only compiled

So far I've tried:

- Closurebuilder.py

  - pros: can be whitespace only
  - problem: Has base code; getting duplicate namespace issues
- Compiler.jar

  - problem: whitespace-only mode keeps goog.provides and requires in
  - problem: any optimizations of project A break project B

Has anyone made a similar setup work?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the source from project A can't be included in the closurebuilder run of project B? That's the typical way such cases are handled and then should then you shouldn't have the goog.require/provide issues.

Comment: Project A comes to B via npm+github, and it is beneficial to shrink A to one file to save time. That's why B can't (well, shouldn't) receive A's source code. I solved it by getting the dependencies from closurebuilder.py and simply concatenating them together into one file. It gets shipped to a built repo, where B can pick it up via npm, and it gets run through a closure script (that adv. optimizes it and splits it into modules). Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by getting the dependencies from closurebuilder.py and simply concatenating them together, in order, into one file. It gets shipped to a built repo, where B can pick it up via npm, and it gets run through a closure script (that adv. optimizes it and splits it into modules).